# Setting Remix default Compiler Version

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler

Is it possible to set the default Compiler version in Remix?

Each time I open Remix, the compiler defaults to version 0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a. However, there is currently up to version 0.5.10 available + all the "nightlys" (and the list is growing) so it takes a while to scroll to your preferred version to run the Compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [Remix online compiler](http://remix.ethereum.org) uses the version `v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js`, which is set in the configuration files.

Github repo: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide

File [compilerContainer.js](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/src/app/tabs/compileTab/compilerContainer.js) ([line 26](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/src/app/tabs/compileTab/compilerContainer.js#L26)).

```
defaultVersion: 'soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js', // this default version is defined: in makeMockCompiler (for browser test) and in package.json (downloadsolc_root) for the builtin compiler
```

File [package.json](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/package.json) ([line 155](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/package.json#L155)).

```
"downloadsolc_root": "wget --no-check-certificate https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js -O soljson.js",
```

File [makeMockCompiler.js](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/ci/makeMockCompiler.js) ([line 6](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/ci/makeMockCompiler.js#L6)).

```
var defaultVersion = 'v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62'
```

When you visit [Remix online](http://remix.ethereum.org), you can see pressing F12 (console) the following:

```
Loading https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js without worker
```

---

#### Change default version

**Option 1: Remix online**

You can customize the URL with your preferred compiler version, like that:

https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.5.10+commit.5a6ea5b1.js

**Option 2: Remix running locally**

You can run Remix in localhost following the instructions [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide#installation) (cloning the repository).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide.git
$ cd remix-ide
```

**Before you do `npm install` make sure you've changed the compiler version in the three files above:**

File compilerContainer.js:

```
defaultVersion: 'soljson-v0.5.10+commit.5a6ea5b1.js', // this default version is defined: in makeMockCompiler (for browser test) and in package.json (downloadsolc_root) for the builtin compiler
```

File package.json:

```
"downloadsolc_root": "wget --no-check-certificate https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/soljson-v0.5.10+commit.5a6ea5b1.js -O soljson.js",
```

File makeMockCompiler.js:

```
var defaultVersion = 'v0.5.10+commit.5a6ea5b1'
```

After that you can continue the instalation with `npm install`. To run, write `npm start`, visit `127.0.0.1:8080` and in the console (F12) you will see the following:

```
Loading https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/soljson-v0.5.10+commit.5a6ea5b1.js without worker
```

Remix will load locally with your preferred compiler version.

Comment: Thanks Alberto. The online version is the one I'm using so Option 1 works fine for me, but thanks for the detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

From [their Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ethereum/remix):

> [as of the time of writing] There is no default option. Compiler version is set in the URL. So it only depends on that.

An alternative to setting a default compiler would be to bookmark the URL of the compiler version you want to "set as default". Whenever you want to use remix, you can then just click on the bookmark to load the default compiler.

Comment: Thanks Shane - I should have checked on their Glitter channel first...Bookmarking the specific URL works fine